# Wrong service startup order when not booting into single-user mode

Tags: linux, debian, zfs, sysvinit

I'm asking about a Debian Wheezy system running sysvinit and ZFS on Linux. While my problem manifests itself with ZFS, I strongly suspect that the  underlying problem is not ZFS-specific.

For some reason, if I boot the system normally, `zfs-import` runs *before* `cryptdisks-early` during the system startup sequence. This is a problem, because I have ZFS pools on LUKS devices which then fail to import because the LUKS devices aren't yet available decrypted, and as a consequence lots of other things fail because they expect things to be available in the file system which aren't.

However, it seems like if I boot into single-user mode (by appending `single` to the kernel command line), `cryptdisks-early` runs before `zfs-import` just the way I want it to.

I cannot recall any time recently when the above has *not* been the case, but I can't guarantee that the services haven't automatically been started in the correct order when booting normally. I believe that this all started with a for me pretty large ZoL upgrade, with basically brand new init scripts that prompted some adjustments e.g. in /etc/insserv.conf.d as compared to the previous configuration, but I also suspect that the init scripts themselves are fine, just that something about the startup order gets messed up somehow.

Looking through /etc/rc?.d, I find in /etc/rcS.d among many others:

- `S10cryptdisks-early`
- `S11zfs-import`
- `S12cryptdisks`

Naiively, it thus seems like everything should start in the correct order, but obviously, that doesn't always happen.

`/etc/insserv.conf.d/zfs-mount` contains `$local_fs +zfs`, which is expected (mounting ZFS file systems is part of providing `local_fs`). Note that in ZFS, import and mount are two distinct operations, where the import happens before the mount. (It is possible to import a ZFS pool without mounting any of its file systems, but not to mount any ZFS file system without having imported the pool the file system is stored on. Normally, and on my system, ZFS file systems are mounted automatically when the pool is imported.)

As a workaround to make sure the system actually boots cleanly, I have edited `/etc/init.d/zfs-import` to make it manually start `cryptdisks-early` before proceeding in its do_start. I would however much rather accomplish the same goal by fixing some configuration settings (which I suspect is possible).

I can't seem to find anything specific about the relative order of `zfs-import` and `cryptdisks-early` but I could be overlooking something obvious there.

**I want to ensure that the system *consistently* starts (and waits for it to start; it can take a while) `cryptdisks-early` *before* trying to start `zfs-import`. What changes do I need to make to the system configuration files?**

`/etc/init.d/.depend.start` doesn't list anything relevant, but `/etc/init.d/.depend.boot` does mention ZFS and cryptdisks together as seen in this extract from it:

```
cryptdisks: checkroot.sh cryptdisks-early udev mdadm-raid
cryptdisks-early: checkroot.sh udev mdadm-raid
zfs-mount: mountall.sh mountall-bootclean.sh cryptdisks cryptdisks-early zfs-import
zfs-import: mtab.sh
```

So if I'm reading that right, zfs-mount depends on zfs-import and cryptdisks, but zfs-import itself doesn't depend on cryptdisks, so init is free to start zfs-import *before* cryptdisks or even cryptdisks-early. Which is exactly the behavior I'm getting in practice, but not what the file names under /etc/rcS.d would seem to indicate.

I'll be happy to provide additional information if needed; just tell me what might be relevant.

Comment: Under `/etc/init.d` have a look at `.depend.boot` and `.depend.start`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I find `zfs-import: mtab.sh` and `zfs-mount: mountall.sh mountall-bootclean.sh cryptdisks cryptdisks-early zfs-import` in `.depend.boot` (nothing cryptdisks-related in .depend.start, and the only ZFS-related entries there are unrelated to my problems; specifically zfs-zed and zfs-share).

Comment: Try adding `cryptdisks` to the `Required-Start:` header field of `/etc/init.d/zfs-import`, then run `insserv zfs-import` and re-check `.depend.boot`. Btw. what does `+zfs` mean in `/etc/insserv.conf.d/zfs-mount`? Is there a `zfs` init script around?